# How does maven find Java compiler?

Tags: java, maven

I am new to learn maven by following this example given by sonatype's book.This is a simplest **pom.xml** file (works fine). But my question is, how does maven (mvn install) find Java compiler (javac) installed on my machine? This POM file doesn't specify JDK in any way. Thanks for explanation.

**EDIT:**
As a comparison, I am following next example in the book and this time, I received a compilation error because it can't find javax.My java file is in, as suggested in the book: `src/main/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/web/SimpleServlet.java`

Now as I run mvn compile, and i got error message below. Why now maven can't find the compiler:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project simple-webapp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/abigail/study/simple-webapp/src/main/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/web/SimpleServlet.java:[4,1] package javax.servlet does not exist
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-    v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.simpleweb</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>simple-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I do have this variable set, but not sure whether it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to this path, say with `maven version 3.2.3`

```
apache-maven-3.2.3-bin\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
```

opne the **mvn.bat**, you can see below

> @REM Maven2 Start Up Batch script
>
> @REM Required ENV vars:
>
> @REM JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir

Clearly it picks `JAVA_HOME`, from your environment variables. Below code snippet from the file.

```
@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto OkJHome
:OkJHome
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto chkMHome
:chkMHome
if not "%M2_HOME%"=="" goto valMHome
```

**for issue, javax.servlet**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or whichever available

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I am seeing it. Thanks. Can you figure out why my above example maven can't find javax?

Comment: Thanks. why does servlet has to be included as dependency? It's also part of JDK standard package.

Comment: No, it isn't - it's part of the JEE.

Answer (score 4):

Maven uses the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to find the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Since maven itself is a java app, it would just default to the jdk that runs the maven goal.

For more compilation options, you'd have to use:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

Take a look at this also:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

EDIT:

To your followup question:
If you look in mvn executable (by default in: /usr/bin/mvn), you'd see it is a rather lengthy bash scriptie that spends a significant amount of time finding where the jdk is. Of course, you can set the JAVA_HOME system property and "help" the script, but even if you don't have it, it is going to attempt finding it, and only when it fails, it is going to spew an error.

From the /usr/bin/mvn:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  javaExecutable="`which javac`"
  if [ -n "$javaExecutable" -a ! "`expr \"$javaExecutable\" : '\([^ ]*\)'`" = "no" ]; then
    # readlink(1) is not available as standard on Solaris 10.
    readLink=`which readlink`
    if [ ! `expr "$readLink" : '\([^ ]*\)'` = "no" ]; then
      javaExecutable="`readlink -f \"$javaExecutable\"`"
      javaHome="`dirname \"$javaExecutable\"`"
      javaHome=`expr "$javaHome" : '\(.*\)/bin'`
      JAVA_HOME="$javaHome"
      export JAVA_HOME
    fi
  fi
```

And

```
if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi
```

Actually, most of the code of the script is concerned with determining which java to use and where that java is located. **However, once you run the mvn executable, that *doesn't* limit it to using the same jdk for compilation/running that it itself is run with**. Herein is where the mvn compiler plugin comes into play, where you can specify additional jdk installations to use.

Comment: Default to which JDK that's runs maven goal? Is that because JDK is installed /usr/bin/ directory so maven can access it directly without any other specification?

Comment: Just a note: I find Maven's approach to finding the JDK (yes JDK, not JRE) slightly flawed. The JAVA_HOME env var was originally intended for JRE location so it might be pointing to a JRE location on your machine, not because of Maven but because of other apps on that host. Therefore you may need to have a wrapper around `mvn.bat|sh` to set the JAVA_HOME env var appropriately. +1 for mentioning maven-compiler-plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

So i just got maven to pick up different Java location from my default:

Java8

```
[tomek:~] $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

but maven picked up Java9

```
[tomek:~] $ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 9-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
```

JAVA_HOME was not set:

```
[tomek:~] $ echo "Java HOME: $JAVA_HOME"
Java HOME:
```

So I suspect it just bring first alternative on ubuntu (ignoring users choice):

```
[tomek:~] $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   
Status
------------------------------------------------------------
 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091       auto mode
 * 1            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java                  1         manual mode
   2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
```