# Where Can I check Apache Maven Java build version? What's JNI Error?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have problem with my maven.
The maven can build the project successfully.
but I can't run the jar which mvn built.
Where Can I check mvn Java build version?
I haven't installed several version of java.
I am a beginner of java. Where can I check Java Configurations?

The third one is pom.xml. I modified it following instruction
by @Stephen C.
However mvn couldn't get the project cleaned.

Enviroment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251
M2_HOME:C:\apache-maven-3.6.3
```

```
$mvn package package dModule=100Main

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ h ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ h ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ h ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ h ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ch ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ h ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\BAT\target\h-0.0.1.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single (batch) @ h ---
```

```
$"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java" -jar  A100.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: /Package/name/100Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
```

pom.xml

```
    <name>batch</name>
    <description>mvn clean compile -P [local/development/production] package -Dmodule=***</description>

    <properties>
        <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
        <compileSource>1.8</compileSource>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <showDepercation>true</showDepercation>
                    <showWarning>true</showWarning>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${module}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.tmn.batch.${module}.${module}Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>batch</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

```
$ mvn clean -e

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project batch: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\batch\target -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project tmn-batch: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\batch\target
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541427/how-does-maven-find-java-compiler

Comment: @Qwerky Thank you for the information. I  changed pom but it still dosen't work,

Answer (score 2):

The exception message says:

```
.... has been compiled by a more recent version of 
     the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0) ....
```

Version 55.0 corresponds to a target version of Java 11.  So that tells you what the actual target version that Maven built your code for.  (You can look up the classfile version numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout).)

---

The POM file is what tells Maven what target platform to compile for.  If you want to target Java 8, you can do it by setting properties; e.g.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

or you in the config for the compiler plugin; e.g.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The above are excerpts of a POM file.  I recommend that you take the time to do some background reading on Maven and POM files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified the pom.xml , but it seems not to be changed. 
 Is jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java" -jar compatible with 1.8?

Comment: 1) Did you remember to run "mvn clean"?  2) Yes it is.  The `_251` is the patch version.

Comment: I coundn't do clean.. Mojo executer? prevented clean...

Comment: It looks like you have a permissions problem.  Try deleting the contents of your project's "target" directory by hand.  The point is that Maven probably doesn't know that you have changed the Java target version and that it (therefore) needs to recompile the Java source code.

Comment: I found that   StringBullder sb = new StringBuilder();    when sb is appended several time,　similar error happens >>>ERROR>>>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: batch/A100/Test has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)

Comment: I removed target direcotry  howevenr nothing didn't change.

Comment: Try installing a Java 8 JDK and building the classes with that.  You can use `mvn --version` to check the version of the JDK that it finds.

Comment: ```
 mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows" 
```   

Is JDK 1.8  diffrent from Java8 ?

Comment: Nope. They are the same.  Are you sure that you are correctly deploying the rebuilt JAR files to your execution platform?